# Controlling tabs in a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to the world of creating Chrome extensions.  My extension will not require any type of UI.  I would like the extension to run in the background and take note whenever a new tab is created and when a tab is closed.  Later on I'd like the extension to do other things but I'll be happy with just receiving tab "close" and tab "open" notifications.

Any pointers as to where I should start?

Thank you so much!
Matty P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with reading about [background pages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/background_pages.html) and [Tabs API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/tabs.html) that allows you to catch those events.

Comment: More specifically, the events portion:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/tabs.html#events where you define them within your background page.

Answer (score 1):

you can detect this using:

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(Tab tab) {...});

Parameters

tab( Tab )
Details of the tab that was created.

and

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(integer tabId, object removeInfo) {...});

Parameters
tabId
( integer )
removeInfo
( object )
    isWindowClosing
    ( boolean )
        True when the tab is being closed because its window is being closed.

Detail at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html